# How to enable logging in new Azure VMs, automatically?

Tags: azure, logging, monitor

I have created a custom OS images on Azure containing my app, `omsagent`, and a configuration file to track my application logs. I verified that the custom logs were available on Log Analytics Workspace for that VM.

When I create a new VM with this custom OS, using Python SDK, I don't receive logs in the workspace. I verified that `omsagent` is working. It is sending heartbeats that are visible on the `Log Analytics Workspace > Insights > Agents`.

I found out that the new is was not `Connected` to the workspace.

So my question is how do I automatically connect a VM to Log Analytics Workspace at creation time?

Answer (score 0):

I would advise against baking the Log Analytics Agent (OMS Agent) into the image directly - Azure doesn't recommend this kind of setup. Instead, you should be using an Azure Policy that they provide exactly for this scenario.

We have dozens of VMs and Scale Sets we need to manage with Log Analytics Agent installed on each of them when we build the custom images. In the beginning everything was working fine but a couple of months later those images stopped working.

After spending some time investigating with the Azure team we found out that the agent's certificate wasn't being renewed and it wouldn't connect to the Workspace automatically. Even worse was that because of this, it was failing all our images builds.

We were told that this is not the right practice and we should look at Azure Policies. They are rather easy to setup - just assign once and forget about them. It's also good for compliance and will let you know if there's any machine that's non-compliant.

Check [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/policy-reference#:%7E:text=Deploy%20Log%20Analytics%20agent%20for%20Windows%20virtual%20machines%20if%20the%20virtual%20machine%20image%20is%20in%20the%20list%20defined%20and%20the%20agent%20is%20not%20installed.) link for more info about Azure Monitor policies.

And [this](https://portal.azure.com/#blade/Microsoft_Azure_Policy/PolicyDetailBlade/definitionId/%2Fproviders%2FMicrosoft.Authorization%2FpolicyDefinitions%2F0868462e-646c-4fe3-9ced-a733534b6a2c) link will open your Azure Portal directly into the policies page for Windows VMs.

Here's a preview of the policies available:

[image]